# Junit | comparing dynamic objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

How do I compare dynamic object types in Junit for example:-

```
while (objList.hasNext()) {
      Object<String> obj = objList.next();
      Assert.assertEquals("expected", obj); 
}
```

In this scenario if one occurrence is failed the whole test will fail. Is it a good approach if I use a condition before the assert test to pin point the expected String

like this:

```
while (objList.hasNext()) {
      Object<String> obj = objList.next();
      if (obj.equals("expected")) {
           Assert.assertEquals("expected", obj); 
      }
}
```

but in this case there's no point of having a Junit assert test. Because I'm already doing what Junit is intended to do
Thanks.

Comment: What condition to add ? can you make an example ?

Comment: Do you want to know how to assert object equality or what? Your last sentence seem to ask for something else.

Comment: What I meant if I add a "if, else" condition to check the expected String is in the list

Comment: Could you please clarify what behaviour is expected? Do you expect the test to fail only if all elements are different? What is compared to what -- is every element compared to the same value or is it about comparing elements in two different dynamic structures?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [ErrorCollector Rule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html).

It allows you to "collect" errors and output them in the end. JUnit will not fail at the first error if you use this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking here. It'd be easier if we knew what you were iterating over, but assuming that it's an Iterable, you're probably best off looking at the [hamcrest matchers](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html).

For example

```
asserThat(objList, Matchers.hasItem(expected);
```

will pass if expected is equal to an element in your iterable. Check out the matchers bundled with junit, or add the external hamcrest libraries to your test project.

Answer (score 0):

What I do for larger data structures is to use a sensible toString() method and compare this.

e.g.

```
assertEquals(""+expected, ""+obj);
assertEquals(expected, obj);
```

The reason for doing this is that with an IDE (to show you the difference) or text comparison you can see all the values which are different and how they differ. The second check is to confirm they really are equal.

Comment: This answer assumes that `foo.toString().equals(bar.toString())` implies `foo.equals(bar)`. True enough for the `String` example, but perhaps not in general.

Comment: The double check implies that if `foo.toString().equals(bar.toString())` is false, then `foo.equals(bar)` is also false, which is not true in general, but if you make the `toString()` or a custom `asString()` the ability to display meaningful data, it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You might use array based assertions. For this purpose you would have to convert your enumeration to an array.

Object[] enumAsArray = Collections.list(objList).toArray();